# Pre-Process polygons and linestrings into grid areas to partition data

Tags: postgis, oracle-spatial

Due to the size, number, and performance of my polygon queries (polygon in polygon) I would like to pre-process my data and separate the polygons into grids. My data is pretty uniform in my area of interest so like 12 even grids would work well.  I may adjust this number later based on performance.    Basically I am going to create 12 tables with associated spatial indexes or possibly I will just create a single table with a partition key of  my grid.   This will reduce my total index size 12x and hopefully increase performance.  From the query side I will direct the query to the appropriate table.

The key is for me to be able to figure out how to group polygons into these grids.  If the polygon falls within multiple grids then I would likely create a record in each and de-duplicate upon query.  I wouldn't expect this to happen very often.

Essentially I will have a "grid" that I want to intersect my polygon and figure out what grids the polygon falls in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My process would be something like this:

1. Find the MIN/MAX ordinate values for your whole data set (both axes)
2. Extend those values by a margin that seems appropriate (in case the ordinates when combined don't form a regular rectangular shape)
3. Write a small loop that generates polygons at a set interval within those MIN/MAX ordinates - i.e. create one polygon per grid square
4. Use the `SDO_COVERS` to see which of the grid squares cover each polygon. If multiple grid squares cover a polygon, you should see multiple matches as you describe.

I also agree with your strategy of partitioning the data within a single table. I have heard positive comments about this, but I have never personally tried it. The overhead of going to multiple tables seems like something you'll want to avoid though.